# Release Apple Watch app only without iPhone app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos

Situation:
I have a Xcode project that included an iPhone app and a Watch App.

Goal:
Only release the Watch App

Issue at I Tunes Connect:
I get the message that I should upload product images for iPhone.
But I don't want to launch the IPHone app in it.

The Watch app works without iPhone fine.

Question:
Do I have the wrong project chosen in I Tunes Connect or must I delete targets in Xcode?

[Snippet From Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGlYc.png)

Comment: It sounds like you have started with the incorrect project template.  Create a new independent watch app project and add your existing source code to it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps

Comment: [x] Supports Running Without iOS App Installation  is enabled

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS bundles had been inside the watch bundles.
We needed to separate them and it worked.